# The operations for sum([[3], [5]], [])

Tags: python, sum

This is a very simple expression, but I have no idea how it operates.

```
print(sum([[3], [5]], []))

# returns [3,5]
```

why on earth does sum([[3], [5]], []) return [3,5]? My knowledge on sum() is that it takes in an iterable and sums the elements in the iterable. So usually the elements are integers.
For example, I'm familiar with something like:

```
sum([1,2,3])

# returns 6
```

But sum([[3], [5]], []) has two inputs, one a list of lists, and another an empty list. I thought this would return an error, but surprisingly it returned the above result. I haven't seen something like this before, and I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me the operations going on for this example.

Comment: yes, you are correct, it iterates though the list and the first element is [3], then it adds to the second element [5]. the + operator applied to lists concatenates them

Comment: What do you think the result of `[3] + [5]` should be? Why do you think that?

Comment: However, `sum([[3], [5]])` doesn't work. This returns a TypeError. I wish to know why adding [] to the input is able to return [3,5] without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes two parameters :

- the *iterable* (here `[[3],[5]]`)
- the *start*, which has a default value of `0` (an int)

When you use

```
sum([[3],[5]])
```

*start* has the default value 0, so the function tries to add [3] and [5] to 0, an int, so you have `TypeError`.

On the other hand, when you use

```
sum([[3],[5]],[])
```

with `[]` as start value, `[] + [3] + [5]`, it first instantiates an empty list before adding list-type elements to it.

This sum is correct with output `[3,5]`

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to:

```
s = []
for lst in [[3], [5]]:
    s += lst
```

You need to know that the list can be connected through the operator +，even if it contains an empty list, it will get a copy of another list.

About why sum ([[3], [5]]) raise error, see the signature of sum function:

```
sum(iterable, start)
```

If you don't specify start, the default value seems to be 0, which of course cannot be added to the list.

Comment: As I asked in the comment above, Why does `sum([[3], [5]])` return an error then? According to your answer, this should also return [3,5], right?  I wish to know why adding [] to the input is able to return [3,5] without any errors.

Comment: @Robin311 I think I have found the answer, you can see my updated content.

Comment: Oh so in the case of `sum([[3], [5]],  [])` "start" becomes [] ? Which means the operation is just `[ [] + [3] + [5] ] ` ?